# Overriding sort behavior on JPA @Embedded column

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity class that has an embedded object within it:

```
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    /// .... other attributes
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column =
        @Column(name = "FLIGHT_TIME")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "dataState", column =
        @Column(name = "FLIGHT_TIME_TYPE", length = 20))
    })
    private DateDataStateValue flightDate;
}
```

The DateDataStateValue is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class DateDataStateValue implements DataStateValue<Date>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "DATASTATE")
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private final DataState dataState;

    @Column(name = "DATAVALUE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private final Date value;
}
```

When performing a fetch of Flights from the database, using a CriteriaQuery, and creating an Order object on the time column:

```
Path<Flight> propertyPath = queryRoot.get("flightDate");
Order order = isAscending() ? criteriaBuilder.asc(propertyPath) :  criteriaBuilder.desc(propertyPath);
```

The ordering is not what I want.  For instance, if the flight table has the following values:

```
Flight 1  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2012
Flight 2  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2011
Flight 3  | ACTUAL    | 1 Jan 2010
Flight 4  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2009
```

The result of an ascending sort will be:

```
Flight 3  | ACTUAL    | 1 Jan 2010
Flight 4  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2009
Flight 2  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2011
Flight 1  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2012
```

It appears that the default ordering of an @Embedded column is to use the natural ordering of the elements in the order in which they are named in the class.  Ie DATASTATE first, then DATAVALUE second.

What I would like to do is whenever the sort property is flightDate, the ordering is the date first, then the state, ie:

```
Flight 4  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2009
Flight 3  | ACTUAL    | 1 Jan 2010
Flight 2  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2011
Flight 1  | ESTIMATED | 1 Jan 2012
```

Making the DateDataStateValue comparable doesn't affect it, and @orderColumn/@OrderBy don't seem to be the right thing for the job.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't even know you could add an order by query on an embeddable property like this. But I wouldn't rely on it, and simply add two orders to your query:

```
Path<Flight> statePath = queryRoot.get("flightDate.dateState"); // or queryRoot.get("flightDate").get("dateState"): to be tested
Path<Flight> valuePath = queryRoot.get("flightDate.value");
Order[] orders;
if (isAscending()) {
    orders = new Order[] {criteriaBuilder.asc(valuePath), criteriaBuilder.asc(statePath)  };
}
else {
    orders = new Order[] {criteriaBuilder.desc(valuePath), criteriaBuilder.desc(statePath)  
}

query.orderBy(orders);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I might need to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

something like `"flightDate.value ASC, flightDate.dataState ASC"` perhaps, since all you defined was "flightDate", which implies natural ordering of that object